# why the performance of packet transmission is so low

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

Trying to create a raw socket based program using mmap_packet to send packets at fast rate.

The following code is adopted from the example at this [gist](https://github.com/vieites4/rawsockets/blob/master/docs/snippets/packet-tx-ring.c). It does send packets but it doesn't send it fast. On my 1Gbps nic (r8169 driver), it only sends at a rate of about 95,000 packets/second on my corei7 processor (3.1GHz).  I believe it could have sent at much higher rate.

Not sure what is the bottleneck. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


#define PACKET_QDISC_BYPASS     20
/// The number of frames in the ring
//  This number is not set in stone. Nor are block_size, block_nr or frame_size
#define CONF_RING_FRAMES        1024

#define CONF_DEVICE     "eth0"

/// Offset of data from start of frame
#define PKT_OFFSET      (TPACKET_ALIGN(sizeof(struct tpacket_hdr)) + \
                         TPACKET_ALIGN(sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)))

/// (unimportant) macro for loud failure
#define RETURN_ERROR(lvl, msg) \
  do {                    \
    fprintf(stderr, msg); \
    return lvl;            \
  } while(0);

static struct sockaddr_ll txring_daddr;

double getTS() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec/1000000.0;
}

/// create a linklayer destination address
//  @param ringdev is a link layer device name, such as "eth0"
static int
init_ring_daddr(int fd, const char *ringdev)
{
  struct ifreq ifreq;

  // get device index
  strcpy(ifreq.ifr_name, ringdev);
  if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifreq)) {
    perror("ioctl");
    return -1;
  }

  txring_daddr.sll_family    = AF_PACKET;
  txring_daddr.sll_protocol  = htons(ETH_P_IP);
  txring_daddr.sll_ifindex   = ifreq.ifr_ifindex;

  // set the linklayer destination address
  // NOTE: this should be a real address, not ff.ff....
  txring_daddr.sll_halen     = ETH_ALEN;
  memset(&txring_daddr.sll_addr, 0xff, ETH_ALEN);
  return 0;
}

/// Initialize a packet socket ring buffer
//  @param ringtype is one of PACKET_RX_RING or PACKET_TX_RING
static char *
init_packetsock_ring(int fd, int ringtype)
{
  struct tpacket_req tp;
  char *ring;

  // tell kernel to export data through mmap()ped ring
  tp.tp_block_size = CONF_RING_FRAMES * getpagesize();
  tp.tp_block_nr = 1;
  tp.tp_frame_size = getpagesize();
  tp.tp_frame_nr = CONF_RING_FRAMES;
  if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_PACKET, ringtype, (void*) &tp, sizeof(tp))) {
      perror("setting up ring");
    RETURN_ERROR(NULL, "setsockopt() ring\n");
  }
#ifdef TPACKET_V2
    printf("it's TPACKET_V2\n");
  val = TPACKET_V1;
  setsockopt(fd, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_HDRLEN, &val, sizeof(val));
#endif

  // open ring
  ring = mmap(0, tp.tp_block_size * tp.tp_block_nr,
               PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (!ring)
    RETURN_ERROR(NULL, "mmap()\n");

  if (init_ring_daddr(fd, CONF_DEVICE))
   return NULL;

  return ring;
}

/// Create a packet socket. If param ring is not NULL, the buffer is mapped
//  @param ring will, if set, point to the mapped ring on return
//  @return the socket fd
static int
init_packetsock(char **ring, int ringtype)
{
  int fd;

  // open packet socket
  //fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IP));
  //fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL)); //ETH_P_ALL = 3
  fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
  if (fd < 0) {
      perror("open socket");
    RETURN_ERROR(-1, "Root priliveges are required\nsocket() rx. \n");
  }
  if (ring) {
    *ring = init_packetsock_ring(fd, ringtype);

    if (!*ring) {
      close(fd);
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return fd;
}

static int
exit_packetsock(int fd, char *ring)
{
  if (munmap(ring, CONF_RING_FRAMES * getpagesize())) {
    perror("munmap");
    return 1;
  }

  if (close(fd)) {
    perror("close");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

/// transmit a packet using packet ring
//  NOTE: for high rate processing try to batch system calls, 
//        by writing multiple packets to the ring before calling send()
//
//  @param pkt is a packet from the network layer up (e.g., IP)
//  @return 0 on success, -1 on failure
static int process_tx(int fd, char *ring, const char *pkt, int pktlen)
{
  static int ring_offset = 0;

  struct tpacket_hdr *header;
  struct pollfd pollset;
  char *off;
  int ret;

  // fetch a frame
  // like in the PACKET_RX_RING case, we define frames to be a page long,
  // including their header. This explains the use of getpagesize().
  header = (void *) ring + (ring_offset * getpagesize());
  assert((((unsigned long) header) & (getpagesize() - 1)) == 0);
  while (header->tp_status != TP_STATUS_AVAILABLE) {

    // if none available: wait on more data
    pollset.fd = fd;
    pollset.events = POLLOUT;
    pollset.revents = 0;
    ret = poll(&pollset, 1, 1000 /* don't hang */);
    if (ret < 0) {
      if (errno != EINTR) {
        perror("poll");
        return -1;
      }
      //return 0;
    }
  }

  // fill data
  off = ((void *) header) + (TPACKET_HDRLEN - sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
  memcpy(off, pkt, pktlen);

  // fill header
  header->tp_len = pktlen;
  header->tp_status = TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST;

  // increase consumer ring pointer
  ring_offset = (ring_offset + 1) & (CONF_RING_FRAMES - 1);

  // notify kernel


  return 0;
}

/// Example application that opens a packet socket with rx_ring
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *ring;
  char pkt[125] = {0x00,0x0c,0x29,0xa4,0xff,0xbc,0x40,0x25,0xc2,0xd9,0xfb,0x8c,0x08,0x00,0x45,0x00,0x00,0x6f,0x24,0x1b,0x40,0x00,0x40,0x06,0x02,0x4b,0x0a,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x0a,0x00,0x00,0x1d,0xb8,0x64,0x01,0xbb,0x80,0x9e,0xaa,0x77,0x17,0x6d,0xa2,0x04,0x80,0x18,0x00,0x73,0x03,0xa0,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x08,0x0a,0x01,0x27,0x8e,0xaf,0x00,0x01,0xe8,0x71,0x16,0x03,0x01,0x00,0x36,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x32,0x03,0x02,0x55,0xf5,0x01,0xa9,0xc0,0xca,0xae,0xd6,0xd2,0x9b,0x6a,0x79,0x6d,0x9a,0xe8,0x9d,0x78,0xe2,0x64,0x98,0xf0,0xac,0xcb,0x2c,0x0d,0x51,0xa5,0xf8,0xc4,0x0f,0x93,0x87,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x00,0x35,0x00,0xff,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x00,0x0f,0x00,0x01,0x01};
  int fd;
    printf("page size %x\n", getpagesize());
  fd = init_packetsock(&ring, PACKET_TX_RING);
  if (fd < 0)
    return 1;

  // TODO: make correct IP packet out of pkt
  int i;
  double startTs = getTS();
  double currentTs;
  int pktCnt = 0;
  int sendCnt = 0;
    while (1) {
        for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            pkt[1] ++; pktCnt++;
            process_tx(fd, ring, pkt, 125);
        }
        if (sendto(fd, NULL, 0, 0, (void *) &txring_daddr, sizeof(txring_daddr)) < 0) {
            perror("sendto");
            return -1;
        }
        sendCnt++;
        usleep(300);
        currentTs = getTS();
        if ((currentTs - startTs) >= 1.0) {
            startTs += 1.0;
            printf("%7d %6d\n", pktCnt, sendCnt);
            pktCnt = 0; sendCnt = 0;
        }
    }
  if (exit_packetsock(fd, ring))
    return 1;

  printf("OK\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE1**

The current NIC is RealTek RTL8111/8168/8411 NIC. After upgrading the driver to the version as of 8.044, the rate goes up to 135K/second.

Ran the same program on Intel 82577LM Gigabit NIC, got about 430K/seconds rate.

Comment: What is this for: 'usleep(300);' ?

Comment: `usleep(300)` is to give NIC to clear the packets in the tx queue.

Comment: Have you, err, tried a lower value? or omitting it?

Comment: I removed the usleep and it's only slightly better, it can transmit at 100K packets/second. I expect to see about 1million packets/second or so.

Comment: How big is a packet?

Comment: It's 125 bytes. It's shown in the main() function.

Comment: What happens if you make the packets bigger, 256, say..

Comment: "_I expect to see about 1million packets/second or so._" No. On a 1 Gbps link with an MTU of 1500, you should get, at most, about 650,000 pps. With ethernet, you have a 7-octet preamble, 1-octet SoF delimiter, either 14- or 18-octet header, the 1500-octet payload, 4-octet FCS, and a 12-octet inter-packet gap. Wi-Fi would be much worse, and and near perfect rate would be almost half the advertised bandwidth. This is assuming something like UDP that only sends, and not TCP that requires bidirectional communication that needs to wait for replies.

Comment: @MartinJames it's funny: when sending bigger packets (250 bytes/frame), I can send at 145K packets/seconds, a higher packet rate. Wonder what that means.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for catching my miscalculation. It's not 1Million packets/second, the theoretical limit is more on 600+ K packets/second. But the question stand: why can't it send at such a low rate.  This code snippet is supposed to have greatly reduced the number of system calls and hence achieved a much higher rate than the traditional way (no tx ring, just sendto()).

Comment: @packetie maybe it means that you have too many small buffers.  If each call to send a buffer requires some limited resource, (eg. I/O request blocks from a fixed-size pool), then an attempt to send a large number of buffers could mean waiting on an empty pool.

Comment: @MartinJames because it's using tx_ring, packets are not buffered, it's written directly where kernet/NIC will send it out.